# does JHipster come with in build signup/login/logout feature

Tags: jhipster, appfuse

I have used AppFuse. It has in build signup/login/logout feature.
But I have not use JHipster, can I know whether above in build feature available with JHipster also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, just give it a try, it won't take long.

Comment: does it have any other in build features which are useful for general web application, which AppFuse do not have?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know AppFuse enough. In terms of business features, JHipster has user management and CRUD pages for entities, the rest is more about technical features that helps you build your own business features. Technical feature are documented on our web site.